# Android: What happens if the main thread is finished before the worker thread

Tags: android, multithreading

To implement my splash screen for my app, I'm starting a thread from main thread that `sleep`s for a while and calls the home intent. And is working fine.
But my concern is Do we need to wait on main thread? (Currently I'm not doing this)
If main thread finishes first, what will happen and how to handle that scenario?

Thanks,
Venkat

Comment: Main thread can't finish before "child" thread is running, This is a question of variable scope lifetime. So "child" thread is created and initialized in scope of the main thread so whilst it is alive - main thread will be alive as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thread itself cannot be "waited on". The application cannot exit while there are still non-daemon child threads still running.

If you set the child threads to be daemons prior to starting them, they will be immediately terminated when the application exits.

Comment: Thx Tudor, so I need not to wait on main method, and my existing code is safe enough, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for splash screen:

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
Runnable r=new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        // start another activity                       
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(r, 5000); // wait 5 second
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  No need to start a thread when a runnable can do the same thing for you in a handler!